# Incompleteness of $\ell^1$ with respect to $\sup$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to make an example that shows $\ell^1$, that is the space of complex sequences that the sum of the norms of their components is finite, is not complete with respect to $\sup$ norm.

And also a sequence of continuous linear functional on this space with $\sup$ norm that their limit is not a continuous linear one.

I've tried a lot to make such examples.
Is there any hint? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S_k$ be the sequence
$$
1, 1/2, 1/3, ..., 1/k, 0, 0, 0, \ldots
$$
Each $S_i$ is is in $\ell^1$, but the limit is the harmonic series, which is not.

Comment: oh!that's true!i considered it much harder!but what about the second?

Comment: This example already gives an example of the second type: take $F_n(S)=\sum_{j=0}^n S(j)$. Then the limit of $F_n$ is $\sum_{j=0}^\infty S(j)$, which is not continuous in the sup norm, as the example above demonstrates.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I completely forgot about the second part as I was writing. :(

Comment: I think the answer would be better stated as $S_k$ is a Cauchy sequence in the sup norm, but there is no sequence in $l^1$ to which it converges to in the sup-norm. And then some nod towards a proof of this needs to be made.

Comment: I figured I'd given the OP the starting point for all that, which seems in practice to have sufficed.